# Azure SQL server firewall rules does not apply to my WPF application

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

I have started a new Azure SQL server instance with some firewall rules to limit the access. Everything seems fine at first. After setting the rules accordingly I can't connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio, but when I run my application, that's executing stored procedures on the database, it does not block it even though I limited all access (removed all firewall rules).

How can this be? Why can my application access the db but not SSMS? What do I need to do to secure the db from IP's outside the firewall rules?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your application running, in Azure? On the firewall settings page, is the "Allow access to Azure services" turned on? Because if yes, and your app is running in azure than it might be ok that your app can connect even if you remove all firewall rules.

Comment: It's a wpf app running on my desktop. I can try to limit Azure services, but I'm not sure if it will help in this case.

Comment: What is the error message when you try to connect with SSMS? Did you went through this SQL Azure connection troubleshooting: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database

Comment: When trying to connect from SSMS it promts a dialog that says the current IP is not allowed in the firewall settings, and if I log in with my admin account I could add the current IP to the firewall rules. I don't have problems accessing the service, my problem is that it allows too much access... =)